# Only one time flash to user when admin send notificatin to a specicfic user

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, flash-message

I have to send one time notification to user just flash one time when admin send notification to a specific user,Is their is any way to do it without store value in database and the notification pop not even have any close button. Larvel flash message not work in my case because admin send notification to specific user and flash work on current session. One way i think is ajax call on popup close but in that case i have to save value of notification in DB. if someone have any better idea plz share.

Comment: You can use Laravel broadcast concept see the below link for reference. Here when admin do any changes then that respective user notify using 
Laravel broadcast notification message to private channel. httpss://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#leaving-a-channel

Answer (score 0):

i use Session::flash(...) for this

look at this:

this is in controller

```
 Session::flash('activation', $operation2);
```

and then in your view:

```
@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('activation'))
<script>
    swal({
        title: "congrats",
        text: '{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('activation')}}',
        type: success,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "ok",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    });
</script>
@endif
```

this will flash just once

Comment: elaborate more how admin can send notification to user with this logic.